# for_recursive_glob does not take an argument?

Tags: tcl

Trying to do something like:

```
    set filename abc.c
    for_recursive_glob found {.} {$filename} {
    puts $found
    break
    }
```

This never works.

I need to do it this way because I dont know the file names that I should search for apriori.
They are an output of another script.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use this function so I can't be certain, but remove the braces around `$filename` because I believe you're using the literal string  `$filename` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put $filename inside braces:

```
for_recursive_glob found {.} $filename {
```

Or you can do this:

```
for_recursive_glob found {.} [list $filename] {
```